# Why ESP8266 hangs in this part of code?

Tags: c++, arduino, infinite-loop, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Here's the code that makes me trouble:

```
void PMS5003::processDataOn(HardwareSerial &serial) {
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  int count = 0;
  byte incomeByte[NUM_INCOME_BYTE];
  boolean startcount = false;
  byte data;
  while (1){
    yield();
    ESP.wdtFeed();
    if ((millis() - timeout) > 3000){
      //ptrSerial.println("SENSOR-ERROR-TIMEOUT");
      break;
    }
    if (serial.available()){
      data = serial.read();
      if (data == CHAR_PRELIM && !startcount) {
        startcount = true;
        count++;
        incomeByte[0] = data;
      }
      else if (startcount) {
        count++;
        incomeByte[count - 1] = data;
        if (count >= NUM_INCOME_BYTE){
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  unsigned int calcsum = 0;
  unsigned int exptsum;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DATA_BYTE; i++) {
    calcsum += (unsigned int)incomeByte[i];
  }
  exptsum = ((unsigned int)incomeByte[CHECK_BYTE] << 8) + (unsigned int)incomeByte[CHECK_BYTE + 1];
  if (calcsum == exptsum) {
    pm1 = ((unsigned int)incomeByte[PM1_BYTE] << 8) + (unsigned int)incomeByte[PM1_BYTE + 1];
    pm25 = ((unsigned int)incomeByte[PM25_BYTE] << 8) + (unsigned int)incomeByte[PM25_BYTE + 1];
    pm10 = ((unsigned int)incomeByte[PM10_BYTE] << 8) + (unsigned int)incomeByte[PM10_BYTE + 1];
  } else {
    //ptrSerial.println("#[exception] PM2.5 Sensor CHECKSUM ERROR!");
    pm1 = -1;
    pm25 = -1;
    pm10 = -1;
  }
  return;
}
```

ESP8266 is hanging somewhere here after few days of working. I believe this has something to do with `if ((millis() - timeout) > 3000){`.

What should I pay attention to here? Does `millis()` overflows? Or maybe there's something wrong with the subtraction?

@edit

You can see here a line where I print `DEBUG: 32` - this is the last thing I see on my terminal:

```
ParticulateMatterMeasurements measurePM() {
    ParticulateMatterMeasurements measurements;
    for (int laserRestartCount = 0; laserRestartCount < 3; laserRestartCount++) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 31");
        for (int getMeasurementCount = 0; getMeasurementCount < 10; getMeasurementCount++) {
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 32");
            yield();
            measurements = getMeasurements();
            if (measurements.getAreValid()) {
                return measurements;
            } else {
                delay(2000);
            }
        }
        if (!measurements.getAreValid()) {
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 33");
            restartPMSensor();
        } else {
            break;
        }
        yield();
    }
    if (!measurements.getAreValid()) {
        Serial.println("Restarting ESP (laser error)...");
        ESP.restart();
    }
}

ParticulateMatterMeasurements getMeasurements() {
    ParticulateMatterMeasurements measurements;
    measurements.setAreValid(false);
    pms5003.processDataOn(Serial);
    measurements.setPM01Value(pms5003.getPM1());
    measurements.setPM25Value(pms5003.getPM25());
    measurements.setPM10Value(pms5003.getPM10());
    if (measurements.getPM01Value() != -1 && measurements.getPM25Value() != -1 && measurements.getPM10Value() != -1) {
        measurements.setAreValid(true);
    }
    return measurements;
}
```

@edit2

My `loop` method:

```
void loop() {
    Serial.printf("Heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 16");
    restartEspIfNotConnected();
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 17");
    AllMeasurements measurements = measureAllParameters();
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 18");
    Serial.printf("Heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
    sendMeasurementsToBackupServer(getQueryParametersString(measurements));
    Serial.printf("Heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 19");
    Serial.printf("Heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
    int statusCode = sendMeasurementsToServer(getQueryParametersString(measurements));
    Serial.printf("Heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 20");
    if (statusCode < 0) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 21");
        Serial.println(statusCode);
        sendingErrorCounter++;
    } else {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 22");
        sendingErrorCounter = 0;
    }
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 23");
    if (sendingErrorCounter >= 10) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 24");
        ESP.restart();
    }
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 25");
    Serial.printf("Heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
    sendRssi();
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 26");
    Serial.printf("Heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
    checkUpdates();
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 27");
    Serial.printf("Heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
}
```

@edit3

It took some time but I'm a bit closer to the bug. ESP8266 hangs in a place I would never suspect.

Here's additional code:

```
struct Color {
    double r;
    double g;
    double b;
    Color(double r, double g, double b) : r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
    Color() {}
};

Color green(0, 1024, 0);
Color greenYellow(512, 1024, 0);
Color yellow(1024, 1024, 0);
Color orange(1024, 200, 0);
Color red(1024, 0, 0);
Color blue(0, 0, 1024);
Color white(1024, 1024, 1024);
Color black(0, 0, 0);
Color currentColor;

AllMeasurements measureAllParameters() {
    AllMeasurements allMeasurements;
    double PM25[10], PM1[10], PM10[10];
    double calculatedMedianPm25[6];
    double calculatedMedianPm1[6];
    double calculatedMedianPm10[6];
    bool measureNow = true;
    double bmpTemp[5], dhtTemp[5], humidity[5], bmpPressure[5];
    double bmpTempMedian[6], dhtTempMedian[6], humidityMedian[6], pressureMedian[6];
    int dhtTempSize = 0;
    int humiditySize = 0;
    int dhtTempMedianSize = 0;
    int humidityMedianSize = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < 6; b++) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 28");
        yield();
        int reading = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29");
            yield();
            if (measureNow) {
                BmpMeasurements bmpMeasurements = getMeasurementsFromBmpSensor();
                bmpTemp[reading] = bmpMeasurements.getTemperature();
                bmpPressure[reading] = bmpMeasurements.getPressure();
                double temp = dht.readTemperature(false);
                double hum = dht.readHumidity();
                if (!isnan(temp) && !isnan(hum)) {
                    dhtTemp[dhtTempSize] = temp;
                    humidity[humiditySize] = hum;
                    dhtTempSize++;
                    humiditySize++;
                }
                reading++;
                measureNow = false;
            } else {
                measureNow = true;
            }
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.0");
            ParticulateMatterMeasurements measurements = measurePM();
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.1");
            PM1[i] = measurements.getPM01Value();
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.2");
            PM25[i] = measurements.getPM25Value();
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.3");
            PM10[i] = measurements.getPM10Value();
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.4");
            delay(1000);
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.5");
        }
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.6");
        if (isBMP || isBMP280) {
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.7");
            pressureMedian[b] = median(bmpPressure, 5);
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.8");
            bmpTempMedian[b] = median(bmpTemp, 5);
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.9");
        }
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.10");
        if (dhtTempSize > 0) {
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.11");
            dhtTempMedian[dhtTempMedianSize] = median(dhtTemp, dhtTempSize);
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.12");
            dhtTempMedianSize++;
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.13");
            dhtTempSize = 0;
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.14");
        }
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.15");
        if (humiditySize > 0) {
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.16");
            humidityMedian[humidityMedianSize] = median(humidity, humiditySize);
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.17");
            humidityMedianSize++;
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.18");
            humiditySize = 0;
            Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.19");
        }
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.20");
        calculatedMedianPm25[b] = median(PM25, 10);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.21");
        changeLedsColorSmoothlyByPM(calculatedMedianPm25[b]);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.22");
        calculatedMedianPm1[b] = median(PM1, 10);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.23");
        calculatedMedianPm10[b] = median(PM10, 10);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: 29.24");
    }
    Serial.println("DEBUG: 30");
    if (isBMP || isBMP280) {
        allMeasurements.averagePressure = average(pressureMedian, 6);
        allMeasurements.averageBmpTemp = average(bmpTempMedian, 6);
    }
    allMeasurements.averageDhtTemp = average(dhtTempMedian, dhtTempMedianSize);
    allMeasurements.averageHumidity = average(humidityMedian, humidityMedianSize);
    allMeasurements.averagePm1 = average(calculatedMedianPm1, 6);
    allMeasurements.averagePm25 = average(calculatedMedianPm25, 6);
    allMeasurements.averagePm10 = average(calculatedMedianPm10, 6);
    return allMeasurements;
}

void changeLedsColorSmoothlyByPM(const double pm25) {
    Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.1");
    if (pm25 <= 26.6) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.2");
        changeColorSmoothly(currentColor, green, 1000);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.3");
        currentColor = green;
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.4");
        setLedsColorTo(GREEN);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.5");
    } else if (pm25 <= 44.24) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.6");
        changeColorSmoothly(currentColor, greenYellow, 1000);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.7");
        currentColor = greenYellow;
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.8");
    } else if (pm25 <= 73.63) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.9");
        changeColorSmoothly(currentColor, yellow, 1000);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.10");
        currentColor = yellow;
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.11");
    } else if (pm25 <= 138.29) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.12");
        changeColorSmoothly(currentColor, orange, 1000);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.13");
        currentColor = orange;
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.14");
    } else if (pm25 > 138.29) {
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.15");
        changeColorSmoothly(currentColor, red, 1000);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.16");
        currentColor = red;
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.17");
        setLedsColorTo(RED);
        Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.18");
    }
    Serial.println("DEBUG: Leds.19");
}

void changeColorSmoothly(Color oldColor, Color newColor, int timeInMillis) {
    Serial.println("DEBUG: change.1");
    Color currentColor;
    currentColor = oldColor;
    for (int i=0; i<timeInMillis; i++) {
        currentColor.r += (newColor.r-oldColor.r)/timeInMillis;
        currentColor.g += (newColor.g-oldColor.g)/timeInMillis;
        currentColor.b += (newColor.b-oldColor.b)/timeInMillis;
        analogWrite(4, (int) currentColor.r);
        analogWrite(2, (int) currentColor.g);
        analogWrite(15, (int) currentColor.b);
        delay(1);
    }
    Serial.println("DEBUG: change.2");
}
```

The last thing that I see on terminal is `DEBUG: change.1`. So, the ESP8266 hangs within `changeColorSmoothly` method. Any ideas why it hangs there?

@edit4

Ouch, am I exceeding the limit of value in `analogWrite()`? Could it be the problem?

@edit5

I upgraded devices with the new firmware and still some of them hangs.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to see where it hangs by stepping through? How can you be sure its because of `millis()`?

Comment: I have no idea if it's about `millis()`. It's just a guess. I'm running this code on ESP8266 and I'm not sure if reliable debugger exists on that platform.

Comment: Well, you must be using something to download your code into your device. Does the software not have a terminal or console printout?

Comment: It does have console printout and that's how I narrowed down the problem to this part of code. However, it hangs after few days of working, so debugging here is a nightmare.

Comment: According to the Arduino page, `millis()` will overflow after approximately 50 days. But it seems unusual why it would hang here after some time. Did you try checking your math values?

Comment: I expanded my question with additional code.

Comment: So if the last thing you see is `DEBUG: 33`, are you sure its not getting stuck in `restartPMSensor()`? Did you try putting some comments after this function to see if it ever returns?

Comment: I think you misread, `DEBUG: 32` is the last thing I see. Not `DEBUG: 33`.

Comment: Yea sorry. Same thing though, does it return from `yield()`?

Comment: I.e. there are a number of function calls after your last printout so you need to narrow it down further to see if it enters a function or returns from the function. Since you dont have the ability to step through code and your issue is something that only happens over a certain amount of time, its the only way I can think of to narrow the issue down.

Comment: @Javia1492 Well, that's what I'm gonna do but that would be awesome if the problem was resolved faster :) I didn't suspect `yield()` to hang up anything since it's from external library.
@leetibbett I updated my question with my loop method. I put `yield()` in many places because I didn't know it could cause any trouble. Somewhere on the Internet they said that it's recommended :D

Comment: funny story, i deleted my comment. anyway you might consider getting rid of the yields and divide up the work between iterations of the loop. e.g. loop 1 read, loop 2 calculate, loop 3 send data, loop 4 start over.

Comment: when yield()ing, you give the ESP8266 the chance to do other things like keeping up wifi amongst other stuff. So it's possible that yield() doesn't return (crash by system/SDK code). Therefore you also cannot just remove the yield()s.

Comment: @BMelis Shouldn't I trust SDK code and therefore trust that yield() will return?

Comment: @Defozo: you could, but only under the right circumstances. If you're blocking the SDK code for too long, it will behave buggy. If you can capture a stack trace/dump you could see if it's the SDK or your code that is causing the crash.

Comment: @BMelis There is no stack trace, so I'm assuming it's not the SDK fault.

Comment: @BMelis & Javia1492 Please take a look at my updated question.